# Why is my $scope not updating

Tags: angularjs, scope

I'm having an issue whereby my $scope is refusing to update from inside an event handling function.
The index parameter is being passed through, and the array is actually getting modified but the screen is not updating. The other references to `$scope.people` outside of the addFriend function are working perfectly.
Really stumped!

```js
myApp.controller('searchCtrl',function($scope,usrSvc,store){
  
  usrSvc.getUsers()
  .then(function success(users){
      if(users){
        $scope.people = users.data  
      }
  })

    
  $scope.search = function(searchterm){
    usrSvc.getUsers(searchterm)
    .then(function success(users){
      if(users){
        $scope.people = users.data  
      }
    })
  }

  $scope.addFriend = function(friend,index){
    usrSvc.addFriend(store.getId,friend._id)
    $scope.people.splice(0,index);
    console.log($scope.people.forEach(function(e){
      console.log(e)
    }))
    console.log(Array.isArray($scope.people)) //true
    console.log($scope.people)

 

  }


})
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="centerText">
  <h3>{{person.username}}</h3>
  <p>{{person.fullname.join(' ')}}</p>
  <h5>{{person.email}}</h5>
  <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addFriend(person,$index)">Friend me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you should run digest cycle from that event only after calling `$scope.addFriend` method..so that binding will update accordingly

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: show us a code, how you are calling `$scope.addFriend` method?

Comment: what event handling? there is no event triggering shown in your code

Comment: your splice doesn't make sense either. Explain what that is supposed to be for as well as show what `usrSvc.addFriend` does

Comment: The splice works fine outside of the addFriend function. It is to remove the friend clicked on from the array of friends.

Comment: It's ok, I'm an idiot. You're right, I had the splice numbers the wrong way around. Should have been ``` $scope.people.splice(index,0)```